# jquery datatables textarea search limitation

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table field that contains upto 63000 chars. I am using jquery datatables so that I can filter by keywords of my choice. datatables only seems to pickup the first so many chars within this field. If I have a large textarea of chars, only the first few chars are picked up during a search!

Is there a limit to how many chars datatables uses for searching and can it be changed?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find you answer [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-type-overview.html)

*The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used. For example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character, so a VARCHAR column that uses the utf8 character set can be declared to be a maximum of 21,844 characters.*